# kohana form select appending value

Tags: php, forms, kohana

i have a form using kohana form helper.
in a select field i want to have a range of given values. The code:

```
     <?php echo Form::select('number', range(1,$number)) ?>
```

where $number is a given variable. the problem is that i want to assign a 'value' to each select option from the range(1, $number). how can this be done in the given situation?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$range = range(1, $number);

// Generate the values array however you want
// This array *must* have the same number of elements as $range
$values = array(...); 

$array = array_combine($range, $values);

echo Form::select('number', $array);
```